Directional sounds device to be attached to legs of chickens and humans to communicate with them and attempt achieving better symbiosis
It is hard to communicate with a chicken. One form of communication could be making a sound to get the chicken to walk in a specific direction.
In each direction, objects could be placed to interact with the chicken
Based on each object, a different suggestion, request, hint, or, any, thing of this type (that did not disturb the chicken, could be used to ask things of the chicken and reply.
But, first, the chicken must associate the sound to the direction.
I was wondering, what if you had a key (like a keychain), that made a different sound for each direction requested.
There could be attached to the legs a small device with a chip and a speakerphone that made a different sound according to the direction in which the chicken was moving.
The chicken could be gotten to associate the keychain sound with the walking direction sound.
They could move in that direction (or, in effect, be promoted to, upon hearing the associated sound).
The chicken could also have such a device with buttons, and a video, and move a person by breaking into the right place and watching the video.
The person could wear such a device on the legs.
The sounds of the keychain and chicken control directions, could be different than the sounds of the buttons and person control direction.
The chicken could be in a box, and have a video of the person to watch, and the person could be in a room.
The chicken in the box via the video could also watch the objects in the room (to which the person may get closer).
This could include, pillow, water, heat (warm bottle wrapped around cloth), or fodder.
In this way the chicken could communicate needs, with the person.
It would be a nice symbiosis.
The chicken could also control the person, into, and out (of the room, that, belonged, to the chicken).
Thus, privacy would also be respected.
Wouldn't that be nice.
I am posting this post here because it seems to do with bioacoustics.
Has this setting ever tried?
Thank you for your answers.
A downside of this experiment, is, that the chicken might want to communicate in another way.
For instance, the chicken might look in the direction it wants to be carried in.
I have not tried this. It could make a good rewarding experience, or, it might be a bad, experience (for the, chicken).
I do not know.
Who has tried this?

 I've got four chooks and never had much trouble communicating with them. They come when called, peck my shoes when hungry (always), cluck when laying, and cower when predators fly overhead. These inter-species comms seem pretty solid from my point of view. They seem like reasonably smart animals, so I'm not really sure there's all that much more to communicate -- or maybe that's just what they want us to think...
